# HTML5 video player is unable to play certain video files on Firefox

Tags: php, html, video

Please check [this](http://prntscr.com/8dz453) screenshot.

My Code:

```
<video class="embed-responsive-item" id="video-play-normal" controls>
    <source type="video/mp4" src="...path to video..."></source>
</video>
```

These videos are working fine is Chrome.

Comment: Well the error is quite clear, the player does not support the format. Please check with [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats) first. Also you should write the error you get here and not post a link to it.

Comment: In order to check which encoding is used in your file, open it with VLC and go to Tools -> Codec Information.